# How to display a fake text instead of what is being written on the keyboard

Tags: vimscript, security

Say I am writing confidential document on `vim`. I want another text to appear instead of the real document.

Each time a key of the real confidential text is pressed, the next letter of the fake text appear.

Ideally, I want the "Return" carriage to be replaced by another letter of the fake text.

Comment: Maybe you could get some inspiration from https://github.com/mjbrownie/hackertyper.vim. Also two notes: 1) You will probably have to write a vimscript to do so 2) do you really consider that as a secure method? Because that sounds like a funny plugin to write but definitely not a really security feature.